# upload image file to google cloud storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, image-upload

I was trying to upload an image file to google cloud storage, following the google cloud storage documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload), but without success.

The bucket that I created in my google cloud storage is named: test_app-111

This is my **app.yaml** file:

```
application: test_app-111  
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:

# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /img.php
  script: img.php
```

This is my php file called **img.php** :

```
<?php

require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'https://storage.googleapis.com/test_app-111.appspot.com' ];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload_handler.php', $options);

?>


<form action="<?php echo $upload_url?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Files to upload: <br>
   <input type="file" name="uploaded_files" size="40">
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Any idea what am I missing? In the documentation it says "Create the application specific upload URL, using the method CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl()". Do I have to create myself an upload URL? Anyone got an idea how to move on?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I run it using my SDK. I open chrome at http://localhost:8080/img.php Then I choose an image press upload...nothing appears, get an empty page without any errors. When checking my bucket at google cloud storage no image is inside.

Comment: Your bucket name should be something like: `https://storage.googleapis.com/test_app-111.appspot.com`  Delete the `gs_bucket_name` param, and it should upload to your default bucket.

Comment: Make sure you have permission to write to that bucket: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/#Prerequisites  Also, try deploying and upload from there.  It may be a permissions issue when trying locally.

Comment: I change the bucket name as you can see above in my code, but still nothing. If I go to my google cloud storage and see my bucket, i can manually upload a file or delete from the console

Comment: by the way do I need to do anything with this CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl() which refers at the documentation? and the upload_handler.php that used I get it from the documentation, do I need to do something with this?

Comment: Deploy your app, and try it in production.  It should work.

Comment: deploy it...still nothing...how is it possible not working? :-)

Answer (score 2):

gs_bucket_name should be set to your bucket name, not the full url, i.e.

```
$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'test_app-111.appspot.com' ];
```

You can also use `CloudStorageTools::getDefaultGoogleStorageBucketName()` to retrieve the default bucket name instead of hard-coding in one.