# Is it possible to upload image from url to google cloud Using php?

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload image from Image URL to Google Cloud Storage using PHP Library

Answer (score 0):

You can follow https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/ to upload image.

Comment: i am not working with appengine . I am using php API

Comment: This is similar to your case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744548/upload-image-file-to-google-cloud-storage

Comment: i am already doing something like this with Php api but i want to upload edited image in adobe to Google cloud specific folder

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :

You can use this simple PHP script to move files from one server to another server.

https://shellcreeper.com/move-files-server-to-server-using-simple-php/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use file_get_contents() for image urls

```
$file = file_get_contents($imageURL);

$object = $bucket->upload
(
    $file,

    [
        'name' => 'image-name.png',
        'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead'
    ]
);
```

Comment: This question was asked 2 years ago :)

Comment: maybe it will be helpful to someone else then :)